# Extracting the first 10 lines of a file to a string

Tags: c#, streamreader

```
public void get10FirstLines()
{ 
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
     String lines = "";
     lines = sr.readLine();
}
```

How can I get the first 10 lines of the file in the string?

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear - your method is calling `skip10Lines` which isn't the same as *getting* the first 10 lines into a string. It's also unclear whether you really want the lines in a single string or as a list.

Comment: If this is from ypur real code: `path` should really be a parameter.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Rather than using `StreamReader` directly, use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. You can then use LINQ:

```
var first10Lines = File.ReadLines(path).Take(10).ToList();
```

The benefit of using `File.ReadLines` instead of [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is that it *only* reads the lines you're interested in, instead of reading the whole file. On the other hand, it's only available in .NET 4+. It's easy to implement with an iterator block if you want it for .NET 3.5 though.

The call to `ToList()` is there to force the query to be evaluated (i.e. actually read the data) so that it's read *exactly* once. Without the `ToList` call, if you tried to iterate over `first10Lines` more than once, it would read the file more than once (assuming it works at all; I seem to recall that `File.ReadLines` isn't implemented terribly cleanly in that respect).

If you want the first 10 lines as a *single* string (e.g. with "\r\n" separating them) then you can use `string.Join`:

```
var first10Lines = string.Join("\r\n", File.ReadLines(path).Take(10));
```

Obviously you can change the separator by changing the first argument in the call.

Comment: very nice solution, I would recommend putting it behind an abstraction for testablity.

Answer (score 6):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Take(10);
```

Comment: If user reads a 2 GB(9999 lines) file and only wants first 10 lines, would it access to only first 10 lines?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: No, it would read everything - hence my answer.

Comment: `File.ReadLines()` could be a very big optimization here.

Comment: thank you guys for answering. the thing is, i need it to be in a String. because im going to g.drawline() it afterwards. it cannot be a iterator. it needs to go directly into a string.

String myString = "";

Answer (score 5):

You may try to use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try this:-

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).Take(10);
```

In your case try this as you want the first 10 lines as a single string so you may try to use `string.Join()` like this:

```
var myStr= string.Join("", File.ReadLines(path).Take(10));
```

Comment: Instead of `""` one should use `string.Empty`

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();

TextReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
myString.Append(sr.ReadLine())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] lines = new String[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     lines[i] = sr.readLine();
```

That loops ten times and places the results in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void skip10Lines()
{ 
    StringBuilder lines=new StringBuilder();
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
    {
     String line = "";
     int count=0;

      while((line= sr.ReadLine())!=null)
      {
         if(count==10)
           break;
         lines.Append(line+Environment.NewLine);
         count++;
      }
     }

 string myFileData=lines.ToString();
 }
```

OR

```
public void skip10Lines()
{ 
     int count=0;
     List<String> lines=new List<String>();
     foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))
     {
         if(count==10)
           break;
         lines.Add(line);
         count++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This won't compile (`ReadLine`, not `readLine`) and it's not closing the reader at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Reason beeing is that the nested operators `File.ReadLines(path).Take(10).ToList();` will do the following truly:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(path); // reads all lines of the file
string[] selectedlines = lines.Take(10); // takes first 10 line s into a new array
List<String> LinesList = selectedlines.ToList();
```

Especially the first part is cumbersome as it reads the full file into an enumerable of lines. This eats Performance and Memory. The question poster asked specifically for large files.

for this reason, I would rather recommend:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function loads and returns the first x lines from a file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The path to the file to read</param>
/// <param name="amountOfLines">the number of lines which should be read</param>
/// <param name="encoding">optional value, which specifies the format in which the text file is saved</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<string> GetFirstXLines(string path, int amountOfLines, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    // if no encoding is set, try the default encoding (File Format)
    if (encoding == null) encoding = Encoding.Default;
    // create list which will be filled with the lines and returned later
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    // wrap streamreader around so it gets closed+disposed properly later
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    {
        // loop x times to get the first x lines
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLines; i++)
        {
            // read the next line
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            // if the line is null, we are at the end of file, break out of the loop
            if (line == null) break;
            // if the line was not null, add it to the lines list
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
    // return the lines
    return lines;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Groovy, a JVM based language, one approach is:

```
def buf = new StringBuilder()

Iterator iter = new File(path).withReader{
    for( int cnt = 0;cnt < 9;cnt++){    
        buf << it.readLine()
    }
}

println buf
```

Since, there is no 'break' from a closure, the loop is nested within the closure, and thereby the resource handling is taken care of by the Groovy runtime.