# How to delete from one row to the end of a text file in c#?

Tags: c#, text, stream

I have a text file (`filename.txt`) and I want to delete everything in this file from a special row number to the end of the text file.

How can I do this?
Is it even possible?

**P.S.:**
The number of the line is not constant.
It depends on the value of another variable in my code.

Comment: Read the file up to that line, count how far through the file you are in bytes, then [truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537926/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c) to that size

Comment: Read the file till the row and then rewrite everything overwriting the old file. How many lines are present in the file?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966607/extracting-the-first-10-lines-of-a-file-to-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Read the count of lines which you need.
2. Delete the file.
3. Write your lines to a newly created file with the same path and name.

Below is an example of the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int lineNumber = 4;
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test - Copy.txt";
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                int i = 0;
                while(i!=lineNumber)
                {
                    lines.Add(tr.ReadLine());
                    i++;
                }
            }
            File.Delete(filePath);
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath,lines);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is quite inefficient because a) you just read all lines to memory b) you just did so iterating when you can just do `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: @zaitsman are you saying that reading for example 10 or even 1900 lines from 2000 lines is less efficient than reading all lines?